# Indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor

Tags: yolo

I downloaded a a prepared dataset for YoloV7. Also I cloned yoloV7 Repo.

I want to train a model with this downloaded dataset, for this I use this command.

```
python train.py --workers 8 --device 0 --batch-size 16 --data data.yaml --img 640 640 --cfg cfg/training/yolov7.yaml --weights yolov7x.pt --name yolov7 --hyp data/hyp.scratch.p5.yaml
```

I got this RuntimeError

```
autoanchor: Analyzing anchors... anchors/target = 5.50, Best Possible Recall (BPR) = 1.0000
Image sizes 640 train, 640 test
Using 8 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs\train\yolov74
Starting training for 300 epochs...

     Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls     total    labels  img_size
  0%|                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 0/372 [00:03<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\yolov7\train.py", line 618, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
  File "D:\projects\yolov7\train.py", line 363, in train
    loss, loss_items = compute_loss_ota(pred, targets.to(device), imgs)  # loss scaled by batch_size
  File "D:\projects\yolov7\utils\loss.py", line 585, in __call__
    bs, as_, gjs, gis, targets, anchors = self.build_targets(p, targets, imgs)
  File "D:\projects\yolov7\utils\loss.py", line 759, in build_targets
    from_which_layer = from_which_layer[fg_mask_inboxes]
RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)
```

My System contains 1xCpu, 1x Cuda GPU (its a default gaming pc)

Comment: See also this open issue: https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/issues/1045

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe it's a bug in the current implementation. You can fix it by changing `utils/loss.py` line 685 to

```
from_which_layer.append((torch.ones(size=(len(b),)) * i).to('cuda'))
```

and also add a line after 756 to put `fg_mask_inboxes` on your cuda device:

```
fg_mask_inboxes = fg_mask_inboxes.to(torch.device('cuda'))
```

Comment: it worked!! after searching the web for two days....

Comment: It looks like whe you are to train with p6 models, you need to use train_aux.py but it gives you similar error, do you know how to fixt it ? ------ yolov7/utils/loss.py", line 1559, in build_targets2
    from_which_layer = from_which_layer[fg_mask_inboxes]
RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)

Comment: @OscarRangel Try:  from_which_layer.append((torch.ones(size=(len(b),)) * i).to('cuda')) in line 658

Comment: Thanks. It worked,  what I do not understand is that it was working before without this modification

Comment: I also hat to change on line 742 `"cpu"` to `'cuda'` in `utils/loss.py`

Answer (score 2):

if you are going to use the p6 models with yolov7 you need to use  the train_aux.py, not the train.py and  you need to change a couple of lines too:

1336 -- from_which_layer.append((torch.ones(size=(len(b),)) * i).to('cuda'))

1407 -- fg_mask_inboxes = fg_mask_inboxes.to(torch.device('cuda'))

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by modifying the `utils/loss.py`. Replace line 759 of `utils/loss.py` i.e

`from_which_layer = from_which_layer[fg_mask_inboxes]`

by

`from_which_layer = from_which_layer.to(fg_mask_inboxes.device)[fg_mask_inboxes]`

The main idea behind this modification is to put both variables `from_which_layer` and `fg_mask_inboxes` in the same device.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, since it doesn't involve introducing a hard-coded term (i.e., "cuda") into your code.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/utils/loss.py

Try changing the line 742 to

matching_matrix = torch.zeros_like(cost, device="cpu")

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).